# Eclipse IDE Ctrl + Backspace not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Eclipse Java IDE for Web Developers (Oxygen.3a.Release (4.7.3a)) on Ubuntu 16.04.4 and within code I am unable to delete the previous word relative to my text pointer. The command is supposed to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, but this doesn't work. The command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> does not work either.

Is this a known problem/bug? Is there a way to fix it?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm running Fedora + Cinnamon. /bump

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I faced the same issue with a fresh installation of *Eclipse 4.9* on *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*.

I noticed that not only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> did not work, but in fact a lot more, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd>/<kbd><-</kbd>.

It seems that this issue is caused by a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=426557) in the *Eclipse*'s welcome screen. To resolve the issue follow these steps:

1. Restart *Eclipse*.
2. Uncheck "Always show Welcome at start up" in the bottom right corner.
3. Restart *Eclipse*.

This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341928/eclipse-ctrlright-does-nothing) on SO led me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

@trylimits' solution works perfectly well. However, there might be some cases when you are not in a position to restart the IDE / workspace (maybe you are running localhost server) - and you are really used to ctrl + backspacing and the like; I have a quicker workaround - just close and reopen any file that you need to edit. The bug only affects files that were open at start (behind the welcome screen).